# Significance of number 613 regarding the mitzvot

Tags: number, calendar, mitzvah, parts-of-the-body, astronomy

According to [the Talmud (Makos 23b)](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3880) "Moshe received 613 Mitzvos. They are 365 Lavim (negative commandments), corresponding to the days of the (solar) year, and 248 Mitzvos Aseh (positive commandments), corresponding to the limbs in a man".

This seems to beg the question — so why did God create the world such that there are 365 days to the year, and why 248 limbs in a man?

Does anyone know if there is a higher significance to these numbers?

Comment: Perhaps the Torah came first and God made the world to have 365 days and 248 limbs in a man to correspond to the 613 mitzvot.

Comment: That's definitely _not_ the question I thought you going to ask; especially when you said that it "seems to be the question". I think you need a new title. Nothing particularly clever comes to me at the moment, but how about, "Why are there 365 days in a year and 248 limbs in a man?"

Comment: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/tifeeret/4-2.htm

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=644&st=&pgnum=212&hilite=

Comment: @Daniel and why does the torah have 613 mitzvot?

Answer (score 5):

Tikkunei Zohar ([introduction, 4b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35977&pgnum=11), passim) associates these with the verse (Ex. 3:15, זה שמי לעלם וזה זכרי לדר דר - "This is My name forever, and this is My remembrance for all generations."

The reference there is to the Four-Lettered Name of Hashem, י-ה-ו-ה. Each of the terms in that verse ("My Name" and "My remembrance"), then, relates to one half of that Name. Thus, says the Zohar:

שמי + י-ה equals 365;
זכרי + ו-ה equals 248.

Comment: perhaps tied in to the image of God which man was created in, hence man has 248 limbs and 365 sinews. sounds like the tip of the iceberg to a big kabalistic discussion

Comment: There is a Maamar from the Baal HaTanya in Torah Ohr that talks about why "י-ה" is associated with the negative commandments, and "ו-ה" with the positive. I don't remember which Maamar it is offhand. - here's several of them: http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/search.aspx?searchText=%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%99+&searchWhere=0%2F5

Answer (score 2):

I would just pin my opinion that the no. 613 is a combination of 6+1+3=10(ten commandment) 10  is 1+0=1(H" ekhad devarim:6:4) which means 613 mitzvot given to israel is directly connected to the existence of G-d

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root

Comment: interesting. you read this somewhere? it sounds more like a numerical spice than a reason

Comment: Am sure i dont but thanks for our good coment if you like i can provide you more of others

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a higher meaning to these numbers, but the fundamental idea that Chazal seem to be saying is that the Torah is all encompassing and every aspect of a person's life must be directed by Torah, its values and goals.